# Documenting Props in React

Tags: reactjs

In my current project, I have a lot of components and some of them use props of a grandparent.

However, since I often document my props (description, propTypes and defaultProps), I would like to know if it is useful to also document grandchild's props as well.

Currently, I'm not doing it because it is already done in the parent but sometimes I see people doing it so is there a reason to do it or is it unnecessary ?

Comment: The only real benefit to proptypes is when you have complicated datasets. Otherwise its pretty pointless as its already easy to understand the obvious behaviour. So if you have deep nested grandchild data, that is certainly more important than literal values at the top level. Still I would encourage ditching proptypes and writing typescript as Its much more flexible, quicker to wtite amd resusable to share between methods from react components to utility functions.

Comment: When you say "use props of a grandparent" do you mean to say, "consumes props of the same shape as another component", because I think this is really what you are asking? I would say, yes, absolutely document the proptypes of components. If you find you define the same prop shapes in multiple places then centralize these proptype definitions and export them out to where they are used. This allows you to also define/compose your proptype validators in the same way you do your react components. Since it seems this is likely going to boil down to opinionated responses I'm voting to close.